# Can't run dev server in next.js using npm

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have installed the latest version of next.js which is 14.1.0 and whenever I'm trying to use this command "npm run dev", I'm getting error that says

⚠ Disabling SWC Minifer will not be an option in the next major version. Please report any issues you may be experiencing to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues
⚠ Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc, but an error occurred: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\?\C:\xampp\htdocs\next-js-app\node_modules@next\swc-win32-ia32-msvc\next-swc.win32-ia32-msvc.node
⨯ Failed to load SWC binary for win32/ia32, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc

This is the list of things I have tried so far

1. I have installed the latest version of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable
2. I have used this commands

```
npm i -D @swc/cli @swc/core
npx swc ./file.js
```

3. I have deleted 'package.locl.json' and 'node modules' and then run the command 'npm install'
4. I have used powershell with administrator right to do 'npm install'
5. I have changed my files location from HDD to C disk
6. I have created '.babelrc' file with this content

```
    "presets": ["next/babel"]
```

7. I have added this line in 'next.config.msj' file

```
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    const nextConfig = {
        swcMinify: false,
    };

export default nextConfig;
```

I have reinstalled next.js app and restarted computer multiple times

I don't know what more can I do, I have already tried everything, pls help me with this issue.
Thanks

***UPDATE***
I successfully resolved the issue by identifying that I had been utilizing the 32-bit version of Node.js on a 64-bit operating system. To rectify this, I uninstalled the existing Node.js installation and then proceeded to download and install the appropriate 64-bit version.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77864011/%e2%a8%af-failed-to-load-swc-binary-for-win32-ia32-error-in-next-js-app/77866539#77866539

Comment: @crvx I have already done that

Comment: I will try to reinstall my windows 11, maybe it can help