# ⨯ Failed to load SWC binary for win32/ia32 error in Next JS app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

After installing next js app using command npx create-next-app@latest, and after using this app i am getting this error, tell me the reason and how to solve it?

PS D:\New folder\my-app> npm run dev

> my-app@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

▲ Next.js 14.1.0

- Local:        http://localhost:3000

⚠ Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc, but an error occurred: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\?\D:\New folder\my-app\node_modules@next\swc-win32-ia32-msvc\next-swc.win32-ia32-msvc.node
⨯ Failed to load SWC binary for win32/ia32, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc

PS D:\New folder\my-app>

I have tried,this https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc, but error still remain same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder. After that run `npm i` in your terminal.

Comment: yes! i have tried it, but also does not work